# How to build Boost (from github) with MASM in Windows?

Tags: windows, boost, mingw, masm, undefined-reference

Last year Boost (from the modular boost git repository) could be built in Windows using [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987018/building-boost-with-mingw64-without-masm/24950780#24950780).

I got quite far almost a year later, using this recipe:

1. Install MinGW (32-bits) and Msys (bash etc) using [mingw-get-setup](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe)
2. Install the Windows Driver Kit (for W7 I used WDK 7 -- [GRMWDK_EN_7600_1.ISO](http://download.microsoft.com/download/4/A/2/4A25C7D5-EFBE-4182-B6A9-AE6850409A78/GRMWDK_EN_7600_1.ISO)), which provides MASM 8 (needed for boost > 1.51 according to [this post](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7262))
   -downloading the ISO image and extracting the files with WinRAR worked for me
   -the installer advises against installing the DSF, so skip that
   -add the directories of ML64.exe and ML.exe to the path (both required)
   `C:\Windows\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\x86\amd64; 
    C:\Windows\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\bin\x86`
3. Install a 64/32-bit compiler as well (I used [TDM gcc 5.1.0-2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/TDM-GCC%20Installer/tdm64-gcc-5.1.0-2.exe/download)) and
    add its `bin/` directory to the Windows path
4. open cmd.exe as administrator and start bash
5. in the parent dir of `boost`, run
   `git clone --recursive https://github.com/boostorg/boost.git boost > clone.log`
6. exit bash, goto directory boost and run:
    
   `bootstrap gcc`
7. in `project-config.jam`, change `using msvc ;` into `using gcc ;`
8. run:
   `b2 headers` (now needed to make symbolic links)
   `b2 -a -d+2 -q --build-type=complete --build-dir=build toolset=gcc link=shared runtime-link=shared threading=multi`

These options to `b2` worked with previous versions of boost, but now I can only compile with `b2` without options. The full command line returns these errors:
 `undefined reference to __imp_make_fcontext` and
 `undefined reference to __imp_jump_fcontext`.

I cannot find other posts or even web pages that describe these errors. Does anyone know a way in Windows to still use the `b2` options for the latest boost from the GitHub repository?

**EDIT**:

Using `b2 -a -d+2 -q --build-dir=build toolset=gcc` works. Apparently the `--build-type=complete` option is the first of the ones above to break the compilation.

The flags `link=shared`,  `runtime-link=shared` and `threading=multi` also cause `b2` to stop.

Has anyone got a clue how to solve this? is there a patch for MinGW that works for the current repositories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet may be switching to MSYS2 which is a new and improved version of MSYS. I have very good experience with MSYS2 whereas I can't say that about MSYS or Cygwin (In my case that's building a project heavily using boost and c++11).

You can read some comparison [here](https://www.onwebsecurity.com/windows/msys2-succesful-successor-of-msys).

Also taken from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019057/how-are-msys-msys2-and-msysgit-related-to-each-other):

> While MSYS isn't dead, I would say it's not looking very healthy either.

Comment: Fantastic -- so in MSYS2 it is not even necessary to compile boost? That's even better (as I don't plan to do boost development if I don't need to)!

Comment: There is prebuilt boost and many others, use `pacman -Ss <libname>` to query.